# Should I always specify which IFormatProvider to use?

Tags: .net, fxcop, iformatprovider

I tried running FxCop on a few assemblies of our product, and I get lots and lots of matches of the "Specify IFormatProvider" rule.

As it happens, some of those are legitimate, but it also matches code like this:

```
Logger.DebugFormat("Appending file {0}", fileName);
```

Which can be written as

```
Logger.DebugFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Appending file {0}", fileName);
```

The second variant is much harder to read.

So, is it actually recommended to *always* specifiy the `IFormatProvider` or is it "just" a limitation of the heuristic used in the rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only applies to methods with an `IFormatProvider` overload.

To deal with this problem, I have two static classes, `InvariantText` and `CulturedText`, that work with strings in the invariant culture and current culture, respectively. For example, I have a Format method in each class. This way, I can do culture-neutral and culture-aware formatting without having to specify an `IFormatProvider` each time.

Example:

```
InvariantText.Format("0x{0:X8}",value);

CulturedText.Format("Appending file {0}",file);
```

`InvariantText.Format` and `CulturedText.Format` are simply wrappers to the `String.Format` method, and accordingly likewise return strings.

---

You can even use this pattern to wrap other functions that require culture-neutral and culture-specific strings. For example, create two methods, `InvariantLog` and `CulturedLog` that wrap calls to `Logger.DebugFormat` in your question and take the appropriate `IFormatProvider` in each case.

Comment: Thanks, that's a definitive improvement, however it doesn't work for my logger as the interface is out of my control... And those calls were the ones that annoyed me the most :) Marking this as the correct answer, as it really is the most useful one so far.

Comment: The InvariantText.Format and CulturedText.Format methods return strings.  In your example, you can rewrite the logger methods as `Logger.DebugFormat(CulturedText.Format("Appending file {0}", fileName));`.

Comment: That's actually a very nice idea. +1.

Comment: @Peter, yes, that would be a way. It ends up being roughly the same amount of characters, but it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. You are aware how and where application will be used, so please consider following [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182190%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) recommendations:

1. If the value will be displayed to the user, use the current culture. See [System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
2. If the value will be stored and accessed by software (persisted to a file or database), use the invariant culture. See [System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
3. If you do not know the destination of the value, have the data consumer or provider specify the culture.

PS: I believe `FxCop` follows the third rule and let you specify the right culture yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The rule is not the only reader of your code.  If you do not explicitly specify a formatting culture, a maintenance developer will not be able to distinguish between a deliberate fallback to the default formatting culture (CurrentCulture in most cases) or an omission that may lead to incorrect formatting.  If you don't like the verbosity, consider using wrapper methods like those proposed by Peter O.